# Does the flying cart glitch even work anymore?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I went around playing on Java Edition, and I remembered the glitch(?) where players have a button that is their supposed Place Block button, their user holding a fishing rod, holding the button on their keyboard, and they start flying.

I went to try this on my laptop, and I started holding it, but for some reason, in any angle whatsoever, it won't stick to the minecart. Even putting the rod up won't work<sup>[1]</sup>. If I get off the cart and start fishing it, it works normally, but I'm not on it, so no fun<sup>:(</sup>.

This is actually the same problem in Bedrock Edition for me, and I thought that Java will help, but none would work.

So did the glitch finally go away, or am I doing it wrong? The cart isn't on a rail.

> Notes:
>
> <sup>**[1]**</sup> Facing upwards pressing the button whilst holding the rod to get it attached to the cart.

Comment: My writing style looks like Wikipedia.

Comment: Until recently there was a trick in Java where dual-wielding two fishing poles you could fly with a boat, but I'm not sure if it's still present in 1.16